# The set of compact operators that map to any Banach space is closed.

Tags: functional-analysis

Theorem: The set of compact operators that map to any Banach space is closed.

Proof: Let $\{\mathcal{T}_n\}$ be a sequence of compact operators from $\mathcal{X}_1$ to
$\mathcal{X}_2$, where $\mathcal{X}_2$ is a Banach space. Our goal is to show that if $\|\mathcal{T}_n - \mathcal{T}\| \to 0$
for some $\mathcal{T}$ then $\mathcal{T}$ is also compact.

The proof is based on a "diagonalization"
argument that we will now explain. Let $\{x_k\} $ be any bounded sequence in $\mathcal{X}_1$.
By compactness, $\mathcal{T}_1 x_{1k}$ converges to some $y_1$ as $k \to \infty$ for some subsequence
$\{x_{1k}\} \subseteq \{x_{0k}\} := \{x_k\}$.

Using this same argument, we can conclude $\mathcal{T}_2x_{2k}$
converges to some  $y_{2}$ as $k \to \infty$ for some $\{x_{2k}\} \subseteq \{x_{1k}\}$. Continuing in this
manner, we see that for each $n \geq 1, \mathcal{T}_n x_{nk}$ converges to some $y_{n}$ as $k \to \infty$ for a subsequence $\{x_{nk}\} \subseteq \{x_{(n-1)k}\}$.

We now show that $y_n$ converges. For each $n$, there is a large enough $k_n$
such that
\begin{align*}
\|\mathcal{T}_n x_{nk} - y_{n}\|_2 < n^{-1}
\end{align*}
for all $k \geq k_n$. We can obviously choose the $k_n$ to satisfy $k_{n'} > k_{n}$ for $n' > n$.
So, for $n' > n$ write
$$y_n - y_{n'} = (y_n - \mathcal{T}_n x_{n'k_n'}) + (\mathcal{T}_{n'} x_{n'k_n'} - y_{n'}) + (\mathcal{T}_n x_{n'k_n'} - \mathcal{T} x_{n'k_n'})
+ (\mathcal{T} x_{n'k_n'} - \mathcal{T}_{n'} x_{n'k_{n'}}),$$

which gives

$$\|y_n - y_{n'}\|_2 \leq n^{-1} + n'^{-1} + \|\mathcal{T}_n - \mathcal{T}\| + \|\mathcal{T}_{n'} - \mathcal{T} \|.$$

This establishes that $\{y_n\}$ is Cauchy. As $\mathcal{X}_2$ is a Banach space, $y_n$ converges
to some $y$ in $\mathcal{X}_2$. The inequality

$$\|\mathcal{T} x_{nk_n} - y\|_2 \leq \|\mathcal{T} - \mathcal{T}_n\| \|x_{nk_n}\|_1 + \|\mathcal{T}_n x_{nk_n} - y_n\|_2 + \|y_n - y\|_2$$

now shows that $\mathcal{T} x_{nk_n}$ converges to $y$ and proves that $\mathcal{T}$ is compact.

**Question:** I don't understand how to get $ (\mathcal{T}_n x_{n'k_n'} - \mathcal{T} x_{n'k_n'}) \leq \|\mathcal{T}_n - \mathcal{T}\|$? I understand why the first and second terms can be make less than $\frac 1n $ and $\frac{1}{n'}$. But I don't think it is true that I have two operators, $T$ and $T_n$, I can say $||Tx-T_n x || \leq ||T-T_n||$. The correct version should be $||Tx-T_n x || \leq ||T-T_n|| \cdot ||x||$. So I don't know how to fill the gap.

Comment: It seems to me you've answered your own question: just insert in the missing factors. Since $x_n$ is bounded, the sequence $y_n$ will be still be Cauchy. (If you are quoting the proof from a book, then I'd chalk it up to a simple oversight, easily rectified.)

Comment: @user43208 Thank you!